# Can a long Word doc, and resulting PDF, be a single sheet?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, print-to-pdf

I’m coming to the conclusion that what I’m asking for isn’t possible but wonder if anyone here can surprise me.  I am working on a long (70pp) Word MS doc which I would like to turn into a PDF that would be a continuous sheet.  Not even a dotted line would satisfy me. Setting the top and bottom margins at zero and clicking to remove the page breaks doesn’t help and the maximum setting for the height of a page in Word appears to be 55.87cm.

Though not necessary to any solution I’ll just explain why I want this outcome.  The document consists of about 40 ‘entries’ each relating to a piece of music and consisting of a shaded portion (track info + picture) followed by standard text (my commentary). My wish is to avoid both (b) the white spaces that would result from beginning each entry on a fresh page and (b) the shaded ‘blocks’ (some almost half a page high) splitting over two pages, which is what I’d get were the entries to be run on.

I’ll doubtless end up filling the white spaces with more pictures but before doing so want to make sure my ideal outcome is outside the realm of the possible.

Comment: You should be able to print [continous stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_stationery) with word if you got the right hardware. The format within word would still be based on pages. Converting what you do to a Webpage would probably what you want but might be difficult depending on what it's based on.

Comment: Thanks, Seth. I have no wish to print this out. It will be an ebook in PDF, navigable by scrolling and internal links.

Comment: If you only want it in the PDF you will probably not be able to do it. PDF and Word documents are page oriented. A HTML page maybe combined with a different ebook format than PDF would probably allow what you want. I'm not entirely sure but I think epub could support what you want.

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into that as I was going to move on to other formats anyway. I think you're probably right about PDF but you never know, someone may know a way. Thanks for the helpful input.

Comment: The maximum allowable page length in Word appears to be 22 inches (55.88 cm).  You might try and see what the longest page size in your version of Word (mine is set to mostly USA defaults - inches/points)